# strange empty POST output php

Tags: php, output, string

I have this code:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['username']) === true){
    echo 'Username is set';
    if ( $_POST['username'] == "" ){
        echo '<br> Username is empty';
    } else {
        echo '<br>Username is not empty';
    }
}
if ( isset($_POST['password']) === true ){
    echo 'Password is set';
    if ( $_POST['password'] == "" ){
        echo '<br> Password is empty';
    } else {
        echo '<br>Password is not empty';
    }
} 
?>
```

and I have form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" onKeyUp="javascript:check_username();">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" onKeyUp="javascript:check_password();">
```

the function are calling ajax to check username/pass and after it runs through php file, this is the output when I leave inputs empty:

Username is set
Username is empty

Password is set
Password is not empty

Why is that??

Comment: What is `print_r($_POST);` displaying ? Edit, just saw : "this is the output when I leave inputs empty" -> Isn't what it is supposed to do then ? Display "Field is empty" when you're leaving them empty.

Comment: print_r shows:[object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying "This is the output when I leave inputs empty" Isn't what it is supposed to do then ? Display "Field is empty" when you're leaving them empty.

If you were expecting the code not to display :

```
Username is set
```

because you were leaving the field empty, you might want to know that whereas a value is set or not in the field, the form is sending the $_POST['field'] value anyway for each field in the form (Except the one with the disabled attribute).

Try using `print_r($_POST);` or your browser debugging tool to show which values are passed to this PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

What **is** the value of Password?  Are you sure that its value is in fact empty?

Can you post the code surrounding the inputs?  You didn't post the whole form; it may be that since you didn't close the `<input>` tags, the form is adding some cleartext to the value before submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    ${$key} = $ val;
}

if(empty($username)) {
    echo "Username empty";
} else {
    echo $username;
}

if(empty($password)) {
    echo "Password empty";
} else {
    echo $password;
}
}
```

What this does is makes a variable out of the name attribute of your form input field